# Insert Greek Character to a MySQL table column without using PHP

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

We have a MySQL table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
ID INT(11),
Value VARCHAR(100)
);
```

I want to use INSERT query and load Greek data into Value column. I would like to reiterate that I do not want any involvement of PHP or any 3rd party vendor tool.

I have already tried with INSERT query as below. The query gets executed. When you perform a SELECT to the table we see ????? marks instead of the data.

Additionally, I have also tried changing the character set but does not help.

NOTE : The issue seems to seen in MySQL version 5.5 where as in v8.0 we see the Greek data

```
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (1,'ΜΑΣΟΥΤΗΣ Δ. Α.Ε');

SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

The Expected result is to see the Greek data into the Table, but actually we see ?????.

Comment: How can we have the see same behaviour in MySQL version 5.5

Comment: Workbench directly should already support Greek and UTF-8 characters.  [In this 5.7 demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b8a8cb914eabcbf8325fd6cfe76895bb) there is no problem.

Comment: This is a question of character sets and collations. You probably need the `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation. `SHOW CREATE TABLE Test;` will reveal that. What is the collation of your `Value` column? You are using some kind of mysql client software, even if it's the command line client. Did you run it like this? `mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4` ? Please [edit] your question to provide these important details.

Answer (score 0):

5.5 defaulted to `CHARACTER SET latin1` for any table using the default.

8.0's default is `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

To get 5.5 to work correctly, specify the character set on the table definition.  For Greek, either `utf8` or `utf8mb4` will work.

See "question mark" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Note:  In 5.5 or 5.6, if you index a column that is `VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, you will get an error.  This can be worked around in several ways.

See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes